# How does the viscosity of honey affect bread machine results?

Tags: bread, chemistry, honey

The first time that I used [this blueberry oatmeal bread machine recipe](https://www.bigoven.com/recipe/blueberry-oatmeal-bread/2291289), I used honey that was liquid at room temperature. The second time, I used honey that was solid at room temperature. In order to measure the honey, I heated it in the microwave. It was still liquid when I put it into the bread machine, and I began the mix cycle shortly, after adding the solid ingredients.

How does the viscosity of honey affect bread? The bread tasted less moist and less cake-like the second time, so I wonder if the honey caused the difference. Should I be sure to use liquid honey in the future?

Comment: It sounds like your honey had crystallized a little for your second batch? I doubt you would notice, amongst all those other ingredients, and after baking, the difference between crystallized honey and non-. Especially if you "un-crystallized" the honey to measure. Maybe some other circumstance - like the dried blueberries? -- or other.